# Unexpected behaviour while unsetting cookie

Tags: php, cookies, setcookie

I am having an issue after I unset a cookie in php. This is my code

controller.php

```
setcookie("alert",'String',time()+3600,'/');
header("Location: ../home.php");
```

home.php

```
if(!empty($_COOKIE['alert']) && $_COOKIE['alert'] != ''){

    malert($_COOKIE['alert']);

    $_COOKIE['alert'] = '';
    setcookie('alert', '', time()-1000);
    setcookie('alert', '', time()-1000, '/');           
print_r($_COOKIE);

   }
```

When the home page loads the function `malert` works. But I expect it to skip the if condition when the page is refreshed again.. The problem is even **after refreshing the home.php again** , it is **entering the if** condition.  Am i missing any information here on page refresh about cookie.?

The print_r output is

```
Array ( [PHPSESSID] => xxx [alert] => String )
Array ( [PHPSESSID] => xxx [alert] => )
```

**Note:** As I am using `.htpassword` in this folder I am not able to use `SESSION`

Comment: Isn't this line `setcookie('alert', '', time()-1000);` unsetting the cookie? In which case the if statement won't be entered on the second page.

Comment: @andrewsi when refreshing its entering if

Comment: Is malert() outputting any content?

Comment: @JP yes jus - `echo '<script>alert(str);</script>'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling setcookie() after print_r(). You can't call setcookie() after outputting content because headers are already sent.

Comment: as u can c the output, its value gets null.. but after refreshing the page again its entering the if condition

Comment: No the value gets null because he writes directly into $_COOKIE ($_COOKIE['alert'] = '';). PHP sets $_COOKIE when the page is loaded, but calling setcookie() does not alter $_COOKIE in the same script instance.

Comment: after unsetting in the `print_r` the cookie is `[alert] =>` is `empty`. Then may I know why is it entering the `if` condition when refreshing..

Comment: In your comment, you mentionned `malert()` outputs content to the browser. A cookie is set using headers sent to the browser. However, those headers can't be sent once you output content. If you call `malert()` and it outputs content, calling `setcookie()` right after won't actually set your cookie because headers are already sent! Solution would be to call `malert()` AFTER setting your cookies.

Comment: I did not know that A cookie is set using headers sent to the browser and cant be sent after headers sent.. ThanX accepting for the comment .

Answer (score 0):

just try `setcookie('alert', '', 1);`

Comment: does it work as expected when you just goto the page again, no refresh?